# How to insert node in all intersecting quads in QuadTree?

Tags: c#, quadtree

I have a QuadTree but the insert method is not working like I want it to. Right now it only inserts in the first intersecting quad it sees. The aim is that all nodes are inserted in all the quads its intersecting with. For example: when a node is on the border of two quads, it is inserted in both quads. Can somebody help me to get the insert method to where it is inserted in all intersecting quads?

**This is my current implementation:**

*This is the call to insert the nodes:*

```
QuadTree = new QuadTreeNode < Artist > (new Rect(0, 0, Width, Height), 1);
foreach(Artist artist in Artists) {
  QuadTree.Insert(artist);
}
```

*This is my QuadTree class:*

```
public interface WithRect {
  Rect Rect {
    get;
  }
}

public class QuadTreeNode < T > where T: WithRect {
  Rect bounds;
  List < T > contents;
  int numberOfNodesInserted = 0;
  int max = 4;
  int depth = 0;
  int maxDepth = 6;
  bool divided;

  QuadTreeNode < T > TopLeft;
  QuadTreeNode < T > TopRight;
  QuadTreeNode < T > BottomLeft;
  QuadTreeNode < T > BottomRight;

  public QuadTreeNode(Rect _bounds, int _depth) {
    depth = _depth;
    bounds = _bounds;
    contents = new List < T > ();
    divided = false;
  }

  public void DivideQuad() {
    int newDepth = depth + 1;
    double x = bounds.X;
    double y = bounds.Y;
    double width = bounds.Width;
    double height = bounds.Height;

    TopLeft = new QuadTreeNode < T > (new Rect(x, y, width / 2, height / 2), newDepth);
    TopRight = new QuadTreeNode < T > (new Rect(x + width / 2, y, width / 2, height / 2), newDepth);
    BottomLeft = new QuadTreeNode < T > (new Rect(x, y + height / 2, width / 2, height / 2), newDepth);
    BottomRight = new QuadTreeNode < T > (new Rect(x + width / 2, y + height / 2, width / 2, height / 2), newDepth);
    divided = true;

    foreach(T item in contents) {
      Insert(item);
    }
    contents.Clear();
  }

  public bool Insert(T item) {
    if (!bounds.IntersectsWith(item.Rect)) return false;
    
    if (numberOfNodesInserted < max || depth == maxDepth) {
      contents.Add(item);
      numberOfNodesInserted++;
      return true;
    }
    else {
      if (!divided) {
        DivideQuad();
      }

      if (TopLeft.Insert(item)) return true;
      else if (TopRight.Insert(item)) return true;
      else if (BottomLeft.Insert(item)) return true;
      else if (BottomRight.Insert(item)) return true;
      else return false;
    }
  }

  public void GetBounds(ref List < Rect > results) {
    if (bounds != null) results.Add(bounds);

    if (TopLeft != null) TopLeft.GetBounds(ref results);
    if (TopRight != null) TopRight.GetBounds(ref results);
    if (BottomLeft != null) BottomLeft.GetBounds(ref results);
    if (BottomRight != null) BottomRight.GetBounds(ref results);
  }

  public void Query(T item, ref List < T > collisions, List < Square > squares, int squareWidth, int squareHeight) {
    if (item.Rect.IntersectsWith(bounds)) {
      if (divided) {
        TopLeft.Query(item, ref collisions, squares, squareWidth, squareHeight);
        TopRight.Query(item, ref collisions, squares, squareWidth, squareHeight);
        BottomLeft.Query(item, ref collisions, squares, squareWidth, squareHeight);
        BottomRight.Query(item, ref collisions, squares, squareWidth, squareHeight);
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < contents.Count; i++) {
        if (item.Rect != contents[i].Rect) {
          if (item.Rect.IntersectsWith(contents[i].Rect)) {
            if (!collisions.Contains(contents[i])) {
              collisions.Add(contents[i]);
            }
          }
        }
        foreach(Square square in squares) {
          if (square.IsVisited) {
            if (item.Rect.IntersectsWith(new Rect(square.X * squareWidth, square.Y * squareHeight, squareWidth, squareHeight))) {
              if (!collisions.Contains(contents[i])) {
                collisions.Add(contents[i]);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `else` from `else if` to ensure a item is inserted to each of its subnodes.

```
if (TopLeft.Insert(item)) return true;
else if (TopRight.Insert(item)) return true;
else if (BottomLeft.Insert(item)) return true;
else if (BottomRight.Insert(item)) return true;
else return false;
```

should be

```
var result = TopLeft.Insert(item);
result  |= TopRight.Insert(item);
result  |= BottomLeft.Insert(item);
result  |= BottomRight.Insert(item);
return result;
```

Another problem is

```
if (numberOfNodesInserted < max || depth == maxDepth)
```

you should never insert items to the node if it is divided, so it should be:

```
if (!divided && (numberOfNodesInserted < max || depth == maxDepth))
```

That is, assuming you are only storing items in the leaf-nodes.

Comment: I have added the complete QuadTree class. maybe this helps you.

Comment: @Marcel added another possible problem.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/920175ba01c57d08ea0ba5ac59c7c509 -> thanks for the suggestions. but it looks like it still is not working exactly as i want. If you look at the bottom left one and the one right next to it you can see an element on the border. The right one should be divided, as it is supposed to be in both. but it looks like it is only inserted in the left one. Could it be the insertectsWith does not register it as being in the right one?

Comment: @Marcel It is possible that the intersection logic does not work correctly. I would recommend writing unit tests for things like intersection, and test edge cases, like if a value is exactly on the border, and if splitting the quad produces correct values for all cases. If you are using floating point units it might be possible that the rectangles either overlap or have gaps between them due to limited precision.

Comment: I read the else if to else part wrong. I removed the elses from it, but forgot the part of the way you suggested the result part. That's why it was not working . Thanks